# Pick up the right article

Tags: word-usage

Today i wanna ask you how to pick up the right article for a word? Is there any rule that applies for the articles. For example why ***Die Milch*** instead of ***Das Milch*** or ***Der Milch***? I think the article must be picked up, according to the word's ending. I don't really know. One of the solutions would be to learn the article mechanically for each word, but there must be a easier and logical solution. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Except some endings (f. e. -schaft, -ung) there is no any rule. You have to remember the article for almost every single word. And even worse - the meaning of some words depends on the article

Comment: Please take your time to investigate whether a question has already been asked or not. In addition please also read the [help] and our [meta] to make sure that future questions will be on topic here. If multiple questions do not meet our standards you are in risk of [getting an automatic ban for asking](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). We all want to avoid this as a question ban can not easily be removed again.

Comment: You need to learn it "mechanically" (as you call it, or "by heart" as would I prefer to call it). While speaking your brain has no time to think about "what was the rule here... uh... uh... um... wait a moment... words with an -a at the end usually are female... uh..." Your brain must have formed a fix tie between the word and its genus. It will form this tie by repeated use. So: read books! Speak to friends! Write letters! Use the language!